# Unable to access url route when typing in url using react-router

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, react-router

Just trying to get dynamic routes working with react router - but when I type the url in, say localhost:3000/5 for example, I get the error "cannot GET /5". My router is set up as follows:

```
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
                    <div>
                        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                        <Route path="/:id" component={Profile} />
                    </div>
                </ConnectedRouter>
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

And below is my server and server middleware:

Middleware:

```
module.exports = app => {
app.use(webpackHotMiddleware(compiler, {
    log: console.log
}))

app.use(webpackDevMiddleware(compiler, {
    publicPath: config.output.publicPath,
    stats: {colors: true}
}))

app.use(morgan('dev'))
app.use(express.static('dist'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

}
```

Server:

```
require('./middleware')(app);
const people = [];

app.on('listening', () => {
    controllers.getPeopleData(people);
});

app.get('/people', (req, res) => {
    const sortedPeople = controllers.alphabetizePeople(people);
    res.json(sortedPeople);
})

app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  if (err) {
    res.status(500).send(err);
    console.log(err.message);
  }
  next();
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    app.emit('listening');
});
console.log('listening on 3000');
```

Any input is greatly appreciated - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, 5 is not defined. This error is due to this route is not declared in `Router`. It is the proccess:

Try in a .jsx for example: indexRoutes.jsx:

```
import { Router, Route, browserHistory} from 'react-router';

import page5 from './your_route/5.jsx';

export default class Routes extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
         super()
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Router history={browserHistory}>                
                 <Route path="/5" component={page5}/> 
            </Router>
         );
    }
```

When this is done, in your ´index.js´ (the js root of the proyect) put:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import IndexRoutes from './routes/IndexRoutes.jsx'; //this route could be diffentent. Make sure you put the correct.

// Render the main component into the dom
ReactDOM.render(<IndexRoutes/>, document.getElementById('idRoot'));
```

Now, when you put in your browser `localhost:3000/5` you will see the component that you have defined in `./your_route/5.jsx`

Comment: Thank you for the response! Shouldn't the /:id allow me to go to any route that is a number? That is my goal, but even so, If I change the :/id to a 5, (ie   `<Route path="/5" component={Profile} />` I get the same error unfortunately

Comment: try to put into your file (on the first line) this:

import Profile from './your_route/profile.jsx';

Comment: I already have that in my code - I left all my imports out too keep the code snippet short :)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my express server wasn't configured to be a pushstate server. Adding the following code after all my routes in the server fixed the issue.

```
app.get('*', function(request, response){
  response.sendfile('./dist/index.html');
});
```